# Django formset without add new row

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using django formset to list some data. There won't be new additions to this data. So there won't new row int the db. Only existing rows will be changed.
So i don't want to see new addition row at the end of the list. I googled but couldn't find this kind of usage. How can i remove or don't show this last  new data add row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the keyword argument `extra=0` when you instantiate the formset. This is clearly mentioned (and early on) in the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/